# What's the best way to split the content to the layout?

Tags: php

Recently, I wrote a small and functionally CMS, without OOP logic, and with the famous bad practice to include the header, the content and the footer:

```
<?php
     require_once("header.php");

     //Content

     require_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Now, I'm trying to setting up a new CMS, based on the **template engine**. I read a lot of articles about *Smarty & CO*. but I think it's not completly clear because you need to learn this specific language.
So how can I do this?
I've been searching for this and just can’t seems to find anything that would fit the bill....

**Thanks** in adavance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is separate the bits of code that generate the content's *data* and the bits of code that *display* the data. In MVC-land the data part would be handled Model/Controller, and the display by the View. To paraphrase your code:

```
<?php
require('data.php');
require('header.php');
require('display.php');
require('footer.php');
```

Which logically simplifies to:

```
<?php
require('data.php');
require('display.php');
```

Your `data.php` will do nothing but generate the data into particular variables that your `display.php` will then take and turn into displayable content. It's best to do all of the content-related work before outputting anything in case you want to go back and change something in an HTML header [ie: page title] or perform an HTTP redirect or other `header()` operation.

It's a good idea to look into the MVC-style of coding for something like this, I've found the following two pages to be extremely useful in understanding, and then creating an MVC app.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/03/14/a-detailed-overview-of-the-model-view-controller-mvc-coding-structure/

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been started to make a MVC, and it's perfect! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Have everything go to a single route file with rewrite, then pull the correct files like this:

```
ob_start();
include('page_you_need_to_load.php');
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

include('header.php');
echo $html;
include('footer.php');
```